# ibus input method doesn't work in code-OSS

Tags: void-linux

I could write multilingual LaTeX document in Arch using Visual Studio Code or Code-OSS and ibus-m17n BUT in Void ibus-m17n input method seems to work in libreoffice, kate kwrite, etc.! In Code-OSS, it outputs only English!

Anyway to fix this issue?